# Soundcloud api playing correctly under desktop but not under mobile

Tags: javascript, android, ios, audio, soundcloud

I'm facing problems while I try to use soundcloud's api for a webview that should work under desktop and mobile.
Inside a php for loop, i put this piece of code to throw the initialize method of soundcloud's api:

```
if (!$firstSoundcloud) {
    echo "\t\t\t\t".'<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>',"\n",
    "\t\t\t\t".'<script>',"\n",
    "\t\t\t\t".'onLoadedFunctions.push(function() { SC.initialize({',"\n",
    "\t\t\t\t\t".'client_id: "my_client_id"',"\n",
    "\t\t\t\t".'}); });',"\n",
    "\t\t\t\t".'</script>',"\n";
    $firstSoundcloud=true;
}
```

Then i wrote code to render the player:

```
echo '<a href="#picside" style="display:block; position:relative; z-index:3;" onclick="picside.soundcloudPlayer(\''.$widgets['url'][indexOfInArray($id, $widgets["id"])].'\', \''.$widgets['waveformURL'][indexOfInArray($id, $widgets["id"])].'\', \''.$widgets['thumbnailURL'][indexOfInArray($id, $widgets["id"])].'\', \''.addslashes($widgets['author'][indexOfInArray($id, $widgets["id"])]).'\', \''.addslashes($widgets['title'][indexOfInArray($id, $widgets["id"])]).'\', \''.$id.'\');"><img src="'.$_SESSION['path'].'media/play_soundcloud.png" style="width:7%; height:auto;"/></a>';
```

Finally, here is the method i call after the anchor's onclick :

```
SC.stream(r.url.replace(/https\:\/\/api\.soundcloud\.com(\/tracks\/(?:.*))\/stream\?client_id=(?:.*)/, "$1")).then(function(audio){
    audio.on("audio_error", picside.handleAudioError);
    audio.play();
});
```

While it does perfectly behave under desktop, it doesn't play and doesn't display even an error message under iOS and android.
I know that the audio object is generated by the SC api because when i trace it on the console i get it even under iOS.
an online example can be seen at this address :
[picside example page](http://dev.picside.net/post/2783)

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit on july 23th, 2016:
It seems that the problem was coming from the fact the play action can only be made directly after a user click.
I try actually to modify my code to preload the player when the track is under the view of the user, in order to trigger the play action directly from the click event.